# Group and order by Day

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I want to group posts by each day using eloquent

SQL table looks like this

```
+----+-------+------+------------+------------+
| id | title | slug | created_at | updated_at |
+----+-------+------+------------+------------+
```

If I use this code,

```
$links = Post::select(DB::raw('DAY(created_at) day, COUNT(*) post_count'))
    ->groupBy('day')
    ->orderBy('day', 'desc')
    ->get()
```

I get output as shown in below image, but it is only showing the number ( count ) of post on each day and not the post(s) individually.

[image]

So how can I get each post group each post by day.

Comment: You should really just select all of the posts ordered by day and then do the grouping in your own code - database servers are designed to return rows, not multiple groups of rows (`GROUP BY` is used for creating aggregate rows, not for creating subgroups in the result).

Comment: @Amber I thought I can do this, going to give a try on your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You should call the collection's `groupBy` method on the result:

```
$links = Post::selectRaw('DAY(created_at) day')->latest('day')->get();

$links = $links->groupBy('day');
```